# Why are SymbolLayer event handlers synchronous?

Tags: azure-maps, azuremapscontrol

In AzureMapsControl the event handlers on `SymbolLayer` such as `SymbolLayer.OnClick` are synchronous. I'm guessing that this is an Azure Maps limitation but... is there any way around this?

If not, then is

```
Task.Run(async () => await mapArgs.Map.RemovePopupAsync(popup));
```

the best option?

Answer (score 1):

The events in Azure Maps are asynchronous. For the AzureMaps.Component, I believe most of the examples have synchronous event handlers as async wasn't needed. Unless you need to await something in your event handler, it's not common to use an async event handler in .NET. That said, simply add `async` at the start of your handler like this:

```
layer.OnClick += async args => {
    //Do something
    await SomethingAsync();
};
```